# How to preserve values during Ajax call when HTML contents of page is getting reloaded in response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

HTML Page contains "Checkbox and Textarea" in combination for 30 fields.

```
<div class='myClass'>

 //xyz.jspf included here under
 <div class='myform'>
 <button refresh />
 <c:if test='something-1'>
    <checkbox1> <Textarea1> Account Data
 </c:if>
 <c:if test='something-n'>
    <checkbox-n> <Textarea-n> Account Data
 </c:if>
 </div>

</div>
```

User can fill random fields.

On click of button refresh, there is Ajax call which sends HTML which we update page like :

```
$(".myClass").remove();
$(".myClass").html(ajaxResponse); // this contains xyz.jspf which have no data.
```

What is best way to preserve user entered data in Javascript; which can easily set back on after publishing ajax response content to page? Should i store it in JSON in Javascript? I do not want to write 30 lines for setting each value and 60 lines to get values.

**Update**: Also, not sure if this can be handled with Ajax Controller because a service is called which populates all values which are to be inserted in HTML elements. Following is Ajax Controller Code:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "get/accounts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public String getAccounts(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, @ModelAttribute("myForm") MyForm form) {
  form.setAccounts(webservice.getAccounts(personID))        
  return "/accountliste/xyz";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding a function to store the values in a session variable (could be JSON or other variables if desired ).
2. Then, in your click handler for the button, call that function to save values, make the Ajax call.
3. In the Ajax success (and possibly error) callback, read the session variable and set values in the form again.